# cannot invoke join(string) on string[]

Tags: java

I am doing an project where I have to translate English into an another fictional language for an exercise. I have split the sentence into an array and has pushed that array through an if statement into another array, however when I try to do `sentence.join(" ")` I get the error `cannot invoke join(string) on the array type string[]`. Bellow is all of my code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class piglatin {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("welcome to the pig latin translator!");

    //declares the variable
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String userin = input.nextLine(); // takes in raw user inpu
    String[] word = userin.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
    String[] sentence = new String[userin.length()];
    
    //consonats: bcdfgjklmnpqstvxzhrwy / B, C, D, F, G, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, S, T, V, X, Z and often H, R, W, Y.
    //vowels aeiou pissibly y and w
    
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++){

        if(word[i].length() > 1 && word[i]!= " "){
            String firstletter = word[i].substring(0, 1);// gets the 1st letter of the word that the user has inputed
            String secletter = word[i].substring(1, 2);// gets the 1st 2 letter olof the word that the user has inputed
            int InLength = word[i].length();
            if((firstletter.toLowerCase().matches(".*[bcdfgjklmnpqstvxzhrwy].*") && (secletter.toLowerCase().matches(".*[aeiou].*")) && word[i].length()> 1)){

                String restofword1 = word[i].substring(1, InLength);
                String wordfinal = restofword1 + firstletter + "ay";
                sentence[i] = wordfinal;

            }if((firstletter.toLowerCase().matches(".*[bcdfgjklmnpqstvxzhrwy].*") & (secletter.toLowerCase().matches(".*[bcdfgjklmnpqstvxzhrwy].*"))&& word[i].length()> 1)) {

                String restofword2 = word[i].substring(2, InLength);
                String wordfinal2 = restofword2 + firstletter + secletter + "ay";
                sentence[i] = wordfinal2;

            }if(firstletter.toLowerCase().matches(".*[aeiou].*")) {

                String wordfinal3 = word[i] + "way";
                sentence[i] = wordfinal3;
                System. out. println();//removes the % sign at the end of the print statment

            }if(word[i]==null){
                break;
            }
        }
            
    }
    String finished = sentence.join(" ");
    input.close();
    }
    
}
```

do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call methods that don't exist. There is no 'join' that is a member of a String[] and which takes a single String argument.

What you want is the static 'join' method of the String class.

The signature of String.join is

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter,
                          CharSequence... elements)
```

which means your call needs to be

```
finished = String.join(" ", sentence);
```

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)!